# Select all columns with asterix when joining tables with eloquent or query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

How can I select all columns from one of several joined tables?

```
DB::table('table as t')->select('t*');
```

the asterix seems not to work in Laravel? Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it works, but you have it wrong. Try this (notice `.`):

```
DB::table('table as t')->select('t.*');
```

Comment: To add to this. The `::table('table as t')` part must come before the `->select('t.*');` part or else it will throw an exception.

Comment: @racl101 `DB` is proxy to `DatabaseManager`. Calling `table` on that will call the method on `Connection` class, which in turn will get you a `Query\Builder` instance, thus you can continue with chaining builder methods like `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `DB::table('table')->get();`